# Quando começou a usar "turbinado" como melhoria?

Tags: origem-histórica, girias

Nas gírias da língua portuguesa, é possível usar *turbinar* e [*turbinado*](https://dicionario.priberam.org/turbinado) como:

> 2. [Informal]  Que foi desenvolvido ou reforçado para melhorar o seu funcionamento ou qualidades (ex.: motor turbinado).

> 3. [Brasil, Informal]  Que foi aumentado, geralmente por meio de implante de silicone (ex.: bumbum turbinado).

"Turbinado", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2021, https://dicionario.priberam.org/turbinado [consultado em 10-05-2021].

Em exemplos:

> Podemos colocar leite condensado para *turbinar* a receita.

> Pôr silicone nos seios para dar aquela *turbinada*.

Quando que a palavra começou a ter este significado?

Comment: ... esse uso também chegou a Portugal: «'Tá turbinada, e não lhe falta nada»

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse significado provavelmente tem sua origem no uso de turbocompressores para aumentar a potência/eficiência de motores de automóvel. Carros de passeio com motores turbo de série [entraram no mercado](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbocompressor) no início dos anos 1960, e chegaram ao Brasil [apenas na década de 1990](https://www.webmotors.com.br/wm1/noticias/historia-do-turbo-comecou-na-decada-de-1960) — embora [carros](https://acervo.folha.com.br/leitor.do?numero=3850&keyword=turbinado&anchor=4379263&origem=busca&originURL=&pd=8ce52f95db70f77ec872c0738b076d2a) "fora de série" (outra expressão automobilística que entrou para o vocabulário, significando "excepcional"), assim como [ônibus](https://acervo.folha.com.br/leitor.do?numero=3934&keyword=turbinado&anchor=4333640&origem=busca&originURL=&pd=71b2fe44a4218a8f55830682050f82c8) e [caminhões](https://acervo.folha.com.br/leitor.do?numero=4910&keyword=turbinado&anchor=4631777&origem=busca&originURL=&pd=5c173462474aaccca122d1095f6a4879) turbinados já existissem no país nos anos 1970. Parece portanto improvável que a gíria tenha surgido antes dessa década.

A data mais antiga que encontro nos corpus do português para esta gíria é 1994:

[Corpus do Português](https://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/):

> Date:     (08/abr/97)
> Title:    Governo tenta evitar déficit de US$ 15 bi
> Expanded context: [...] uma medida provisória em elaboração para "turbinar" as operações de drawback (exportação de produtos com componentes importados) [...]

[CETENFolha](https://www.linguateca.pt/cetenfolha/), pelo [Projeto AC/DC](https://www.linguateca.pt/acesso/corpus.php?corpus=SAOCARLOS):

> par=Dinheiro--94a-2: A maioria consiste em novos cartuchos com velhos e novos personagens e acessórios para «turbinar» os videos.
> par=Revista--94b-1: Ele passeia com a BMW paterna, mas de seu mesmo tem um Santana 92, que mandou turbinar.
> par=TV--94b-2: No primeiro, Tim tenta turbinar o lava-louças da mulher; no segundo, ela o obriga a ensinar boas maneiras às crianças, três aprendizes de «Beavis e Butt-Head».

Mas, pesquisando no [acervo](https://acervo.folha.com.br/index.do) da Folha de São Paulo, [encontrei](https://acervo.folha.com.br/leitor.do?numero=10443&keyword=turbinado&anchor=5397213&origem=busca&originURL=&pd=18f7215645c8cd6888151225338b08b8) uma ocorrência já em 1988:

[image]

É de se supor que a gíria tenha existido por um tempo antes de ser usada num jornal, então algum momento nas décadas de 1970 ou 1980 parece ser sua data da nascimento provável.